# How to use implement hijri datepicker on vue3 app?

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, frontend, vuetify.js, hijri

I'm currently building a web app using vue3. and Now I need to use a hijri datepicker but the libraries I found don't work on vue3! I don't use jquery on my app so I don't want a library depending on jquery.

what library would be good for me? also how can I do it manually without a library? and resources teaching this would be so fine.
any help would be appreciated!

I tried to use this [lib](https://github.com/talal424/vuetify-umalqura) but it doesn't work with vue 3 only with vue2.
PS: I'm using vuetify on my app if it would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will introduce you to 3 sites for implementing the Hijri or Solar calendar, which you can use in Vue js 3 using API composition and API option.

[The first link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-persian-datetime-picker) with option API - [The second link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-persian-datepicker?activeTab=readme) with API composition API - [The third link](https://talkhabi.github.io/vue-persian-datetime-picker/guide/) is also a complete document for Hijri or Shamsi calendar.